# FTP Passive mode - EPSV vs PASV

Tags: ftp

According to the [RFC documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2428):

> The specification for the File Transfer Protocol assumes that the
> underlying network protocol uses a 32-bit network address
> (specifically IP version 4).  With the deployment of version 6 of the
> Internet Protocol, network addresses will no longer be 32-bits.  This
> paper specifies extensions to FTP that will allow the protocol to
> work over IPv4 and IPv6.

If the server supports `EPSV` and `EPRT` commands then is there a reason why we should use the original `PASV` and `PORT` commands? We can always use the extended commands itself.

I can see that FileZilla uses `PASV` rather than `EPSV`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server supports EPSV or EPRT there is in theory no reason to use PASV or PORT since the necessary functionality is possible with EPSV and EPRT already.

But, it might not be clear in the first place if the server supports these extended commands. Additionally there might be some FTP helper in a firewall or NAT device between client and server which dynamically handles states based on the ports given in these commands and responses. And it might be that this helper does not understand the extended commands.

Thus it might be useful to continue to use IPv4-only commands for IPv4 traffic to avoid possible interoperability problems with older equipment.

Comment: _it might not be clear in the first place if the server supports these extended commands. Additionally there might be some FTP helper in a firewall or NAT device between client and server which dynamically handles states based on the ports given in these commands and responses. And it might be that this helper does not understand the extended commands_

is this the reason why even after FEAT says that EPSV is supported but it returns an error when I run the command?

Comment: @AnirudhSridhar: Some router ALGs will just ignore and passthrough unrecognized commands, but yes, some routers actually reject unknown ones to force PASV usage.